# Mapping func over dictionary

Tags: python

How might one map a function over certain values in a dictionary and also update those values in the dictionary?

```
dic1 = { 1 : [1, 2, 3, 4], 2 : [2, 3, 5, 5], 3 : [6, 3, 7, 2] ... }
map(func, (data[col] for data in dic1.itervalues()))
```

This is sort of what I'm looking for, but I need a way to reinsert the new func(val) back into each respective slot in the dict. The function works fine, and printed it returns all the proper index values with the func applied, but I can't think of a good way to update the dictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: You should think about whether you really _do_ need to mutate the dictionary in place. Part of the reason Python makes it easier to transform a sequence than to mutate one in many cases is to make you think about whether you really needed to mutate it in the first place. (Of course sometimes you do need to—or at least the non-mutating code is harder to write, slower, etc.—which is why Python only makes it a bit harder, rather than impossible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use `map` for updating any kind of sequence; that's not what it's for. `map` is for generating a new sequence:

```
dict2 = dict(map(func, dict1.iteritems()))
```

Of course `func` has to take a `(key, old_value)` and return `(key, new_value)` for this to work as-is. If it just returns, say, `new_value`, you need to wrap it up in some way. But at that point, you're probably better off with a dictionary comprehension than a `map` call and a `dict` constructor:

```
dict2 = {key: func(value) for key, value in dict1.itervalues()}
```

If you want to use `map`, and you want to mutate, you *could* do it by creating a function that updates things, like this:

```
def func_wrapped(d, key):
    d[key] = func(d[key])
map(partial(func_wrapped, d), dict1)
```

(This could even be done as a one-liner by using `partial` with `d.__setitem__` if you really wanted.)

But that's a silly thing to do. For one thing, it means you're building a list of values just to throw them away. (Or, in Python 3, you're not actually doing *anything* unless you write some code that iterates over the `map` iterator.) But more importantly, you're making things harder for yourself for no good reason. If you don't need to modify things in-place, don't do it. If you do need to modify things in place, use a `for` loop.

PS, I'm not saying this was a silly question to *ask*. There are other languages that *do* have `map`-like mutating functions, so it wouldn't be a silly thing to do in, say, C++. It's just not *pythonic*, and you wouldn't know that without asking.

Comment: Ah, I see. There's no real good way to do this, then. I can't recreate the dictionary because it maps to a list of lists.

Comment: He'll probably need `iteritems` if he's going to get the key back.

Comment: @Clever: As my edit shows, there is a way to do this—but it's not a good way, because this is not a good thing to do. It's like asking "How do I use `enumerate` instead of `zip` to zip two lists together?" You can do it, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just changed my approach to `for key, data in dic1.iteritems(): dic1[key][col] = func(data[col)`

Answer (score 1):

Your function can mutate the list:

```
>>> d = {1:[1],2:[2],3:[3]}
>>> def func(lst):
...     lst.append(lst[0])
...     return lst
... 
>>> x = map(func,d.values())
>>> x
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
>>> d
{1: [1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3]}
```

however, please note that this really isn't idiomatic python and should be considered for instructional/educational purposes only ... Usually if a function mutates it's arguments, it's polite to have it return `None`.

Comment: Really? That's interesting. So pythonic practice would be something like `def normalize(old): old = (old - minimum) / (maximum - minimum) return None`? Instead of simply returning old?

Comment: @Clever -- No.  In that case, you don't actually mutate the argument

Comment: @Clever: Sort of, but you can't mutate an integer (or whatever type `old` is likely to be there); doing `old = …` just rebinds the local name `old` with a new value, leaving the old value unchanged.

Comment: BTW, +1 for pointing out the "return `None` if you mutate" idiom.

Comment: @abarnert -- Your second point is the one that is relevant here.  It doesn't matter if old is mutable or not when it enters the function.  It's the rebinding before doing any mutating actions that makes it so that you don't do any mutating.

Comment: What are some ways I would be able to mutate the value inside the function? I can think of a simple `global old`, and possibly a closure?

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, but the first point is why there's no way around the problem (short of changing your data structure to hold mutable things and passing those around, like passing `[2]` in place of `2` so you can do `old[0] = …` instead of `old = …`, or passing a `MyMutableIntWrapper` instance so you can call `wrapper.setvalue(…)`, etc.)

Comment: @Clever -- That depends entirely on the type of object you pass in :).  In my example I mutate the input list by `.append`ing to it. -- `int` objects are impossible to mutate since they're immutable -- Though you could get some similar effects using `global` in limited circumstances I guess (yuck).

Comment: @Clever: The two usual tricks for passing a value "by reference" so you can change it in the function (C++ style) are to pass a one-element list that holds the value, or to pass an instance of a class that holds a value as a property. But again, more often, the answer to that question is "you probably don't want to do that".